# Mesh Generation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mesh

Is there any subroutine, in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), that takes in a list of points, and return me a good mesh that I can use to show to my colleagues, such as this?

[image]

Actually, all I need is just a simple 2D mesh generator that takes in a series of X, Y coordinates (that defines the boundary of the area), and give me back a list of elements that can mesh that area well. [I can do the rest by using MATLAB command to interpolate the Z value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672176/how-do-i-generate-a-3-d-surface-from-isolines)

**Edit : I am *not* interested to use MATLAB to produce the above looking plot. I am interested in using a MATLAB library to obtain a list of elements so that when I plot those element myself (not in MATLAB itself; but in my own C# program), I can obtain this meshed surface.**

PS: I know there is this [DistMesh](http://www-math.mit.edu/~persson/mesh/), but I am looking for something simpler - something built-in direct in MATLAB perhaps. And no, [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/.../meshgrid.html) is *not* mesh generation.

Comment: The figure you show may be misleading. If I understand correctly, you are starting with a set of points defining a boundary of a region. Do you then want to generate a triangular mesh that creates more points *within* that region?

Comment: Yes, I want to generate a triangular mesh that creates more points within that region

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a [finite element mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method), starting with a set of points defining a boundary of a region and then generating a triangular mesh that creates more points within that region. I don't think there's a "simple" solution for this problem.

The closest "built-in" solution would probably be the [Partial Differential Equation Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/pde/), specifically some of the [Geometry Algorithms](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/pde/ug/f7498.html#f8753) like [INITMESH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/pde/ug/initmesh.html) and [REFINEMESH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/pde/ug/refinemesh.html).

The link you gave to [DistMesh](http://www-math.mit.edu/~persson/mesh/) appears to be another good solution. There are also a few submissions on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) that you could take a look at:

- [MESH2D](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25555-mesh2d-automatic-mesh-generation) by [Darren Engwirda](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/22624)
- [Finite Element Toolbox 2.1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2808-finite-element-toolbox-2-1) by [Rasmus Anthin](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/6906)

Comment: Persson's pure Matlab DistMesh might be of interest as well: http://persson.berkeley.edu/software.html
for heavy duty meshing, however, I would write the code to a csv file and do a system call to Shewchuk's triangle, however:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html

Answer (score 1):

- That picture looks exactly like the one from the [griddata](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/griddata.html) documentation. The example in there looks like what you want.
- [SFTOOL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/curvefit/sftool.html) will easily make the picture that you show.
- A thin-plate spline, e.g., [TPAPS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/splines/tpaps.html), should also do the job.

Comment: sftool is definitely not what I want, whereas the TPAPS seems more applicable to obtain a general big thin surface rather than meshed surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think the user-created '[gridfit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998)' is the best I've come across for a single surface, much better/prettier than griddata.

Answer (score 0):

Mesh generation as in Delaunay Triangulation + Steiner Points? There is a builtin Delaunay function in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

If your surface is the z=f(x,y) form you can use:

http://www.advancedmcode.org/how-to-plot-a-coloured-surface-from-3d-scatter.html

If your surface is concave look for surface reconstruction on the same website.