# Issue about parallel mesh generation

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mesh

Recently I've been studying the issue on parallel mesh generation. I wanted a related open-source library and study its parallel mesh generation implementing strategy. I found [paramesh](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~olson/paramesh-doc/Users_manual/amr.html#locate1) and [libMesh](http://libmesh.sourceforge.net/).

I have worked on libMesh for several days, but I found that it seemed to generate mesh through the library triangle and tetGen. That is to say, libMesh doesn't implement mesh generation in parallel.

So now I am wondering if there is any good C++ or C (any other programming language is OK) library or software that implements parallel mesh generation.  In addition, if you can introduce me some excellent papers related, I will be more grateful!

Comment: There are a few parallel mesh generators listed at http://www.robertschneiders.de/meshgeneration/software.html.  I really don't know if any of them are suitable for your needs and have no experience with them.

Comment: thx for your reply! I have checked that list, in fact, that list I have scanned before and found they are little related to my issue, only a software may be implementing in parallel[link](http://tetra.mech.ubc.ca/GRUMMP/), what a pity is that parallelism is included in the major unimplemented feature…

Answer (score 0):

Write a mesh generator in Matlab, it can already do parallel computations.

- [distmesh](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/) - Simple Mesh Generator in MATLAB
- [iso2mesh](http://iso2mesh.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.cgi) - 3D tetrahedral finite element (FE) mesh from surfaces, 3D binary and gray-scale volumetric images such as segmented MRI/CT scans.
- [mesh2d](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25555-mesh2d-automatic-mesh-generation) - Automatic Mesh Generation
- [Mesh generation in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686265/mesh-generation-in-matlab)
- [DistMesh](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Science-CAD/DistMesh.shtml) - A simple MATLAB code for generation of unstructured triangular and tetrahedral meshes
- ...