# How do I make a surf plot in MATLAB with irregularly spaced data?

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I know I can create a 3D surface plot in MATLAB by doing:

```
x = linspace(1,10,100);
y = linspace(10,20,100);

[X Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

Z = X * Y;

surf(X,Y,Z);
```

But this requires that all the nodes for the height map generated line up. I have a set of data which has arbitrary points (x,y) and a height (z). Is there a simple way to plot a graph which will generate a surface between the points in a similar fashion to `surf`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appologies, after some hunting I managed to answer my own question:

You can use the `trisurf` function:

```
tri = delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tri,x,y,z);
```

If you have dense data you will want to do `shading interp` (or another value, check `doc shading`) so you don't get a black blob due to the grid.

Comment: Actually, the best way to avoid the black blob is to set the property `edgeColor` to `none`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've found your answer by using [DELAUNAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/delaunay.html) and [TRISURF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/trisurf.html) to generate and plot a triangulated surface.

As an alternative, you could also fit a regularly-spaced grid to your nonuniformly-spaced points in order to generate a surface that can be plotted with the [SURF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html) command. I discuss how this can be done using the [**TriScatteredInterp** class](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/triscatteredinterp.html) (or the deprecated function [GRIDDATA](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/griddata.html)) in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672176/how-do-i-generate-a-3-d-surface-from-isolines/1674574#1674574) to [this other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672176/how-do-i-generate-a-3-d-surface-from-isolines).