# Mesh plot when X and Y values are not on a grid

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to create a mesh plot from X, Y, and Z when X and Y do not form a grid?

Comment: This is effectively the same as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939265/contour-plot-when-x-and-y-values-are-not-on-a-grid), and has also been covered in this other question (in which the non-uniform points are drawn from isolines): [How Do I Generate a 3-D Surface From Isolines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672176/how-do-i-generate-a-3-d-surface-from-isolines)

Comment: And here's another question that should help too: [How do I make a surf plot in MATLAB with irregularly spaced data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848015/how-do-i-make-a-surf-plot-in-matlab-with-irregularly-spaced-data)

Answer (score 0):

The example below might answer your question

```
clear all
close all

xdata = [1:11];
ydata = [1:6 1:5];
zdata = rand(size(xdata));

[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(min(xdata),max(xdata),20), linspace(min(ydata),max(ydata),30));
Y=sort(Y,'descend');
X=sort(X,'descend');
contourdata = griddata(xdata,ydata,zdata,X,Y);

figure
%contourf(X,Y,contourdata,30,'LineColor','None');
mesh(X,Y,contourdata);
colorbar
```