# How to plot input and output data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 2 Dimensional input data; a set of vector with 2 components, let's say 200. And for each one of those I have a scalar value given to them.

So it's basically something like this:

```
{ [input1(i) input2(i)] , output(i) } where i goes from 1 to 200
```

I would like to make a 3 Dimensional plot with this data, but I don't know how exactly. 
I have tried with `surf`. I have done a `meshgrid` with the input value, but I don't know how to obtain a matrix out of the output data in order to do a `surf`.

How can I get a 3 Dimensional plot with this data?

Comment: Do your inputs vary linearly (e.g. 10, 20, 30...) or are they 'randomly' distributed (e.g. 20, 3.4, -5...)?

Comment: Related questions: [How Do I Generate a 3-D Surface From Isolines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672176/how-do-i-generate-a-3-d-surface-from-isolines), [How do I make a surf plot in MATLAB with irregularly spaced data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848015/how-do-i-make-a-surf-plot-in-matlab-with-irregularly-spaced-data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your input data is 'randomly' spaced:

```
>> inputs = randn(400, 2);
>> outputs = inputs(:, 1) .* inputs(:, 2);   % some function for the output
```

You could simply plot a [scatter3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html) plot of these data:

```
>> scatter3(inputs(:, 1), inputs(:, 2), outputs)
```

[image]

But a better way is to interpolate, using [TriScatteredInterp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/triscatteredinterpclass.html) so you can plot the underlying function as a surface:

```
% create suitably spaced mesh...
gridsteps_x = min(inputs(:, 1)):0.5:max(inputs(:, 1));
gridsteps_y = min(inputs(:, 2)):0.5:max(inputs(:, 2));
[X, Y] = meshgrid(gridsteps_x, gridsteps_y);

% Compute function to perform interpolation:
F = TriScatteredInterp(inputs(:, 1), inputs(:, 2), outputs);

% Calculate Z values using function F:
Z = F(X, Y);

% Now plot this, with original data:
mesh(X, Y, Z); 
hold on
scatter3(inputs(:, 1), inputs(:, 2), outputs);
hold off
```

[image]