# Surf interpolated data in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, surf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a surf plot in MATLAB with irregularly spaced data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848015/how-do-i-make-a-surf-plot-in-matlab-with-irregularly-spaced-data)

I have such data:

```
data = [
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
...
xn yn zn
];
```

I need to get surface of this data. Third row, z - will be the height of surface. But Xs and Ys are not monotonic continous data, so this doesn't work:

```
[X Y] = meshgrid(data(:,1), data(:,2));
Z = interp2(data(:,1), data(:,2), data(:,3), X, Y);
```

because my data in first and second row is not monotonic.

**Update:**

[TriScatteredInterp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html) can do this.(Thanks @Rody Oldenhuis)

```
F = TriScatteredInterp(data(:,1), data(:,2), data(:,3))
ti=1:10:600;
[qx qy] = meshgrid(ti, ti);
qz = F(qx, qy);
mesh(qx, qy, qz);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [TriScatteredInterp](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html). From the documentation:

> F = TriScatteredInterp(X, V) creates an interpolant that fits a
>   surface of the form V = F(X) to the scattered data in (X, V). X is a
>   matrix of size mpts-by-ndim, where mpts is the number of points and
>   ndim is the dimension of the space where the points reside (ndim is 2
>   or 3). The column vector V defines the values at X, where the length
>   of V equals mpts.
>
> F = TriScatteredInterp(X, Y, V) and F = TriScatteredInterp(X, Y, Z, V)
>   allow the data point locations to be specified in alternative column
>   vector format when working in 2-D and 3-D.

Comment: Yeah, thank you! `TriScatteredInterp` helped me to do my task