# Subtract two trisurf plots from one another

Tags: matlab

I have two sets of data vectors X, Y, Z and X2, Y2, Z2

I currently plot them using trisurf on different graphs.  Can I plot them on the same graph even if X Y and X2 Y2 are different.  Can I subtract the surface plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can plot 2 trisurfs on the same plot. Just use `hold on` after the first call, and `hold off` at the end.

To substract one trisurf plot from another I think you need to interpolate one set of X/Y coordinates to another. Try to use [INTERP2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp2.html) for this:

```
Z2i = interp2(X2,Y2,Z2,X,Y);
tri = delaunay(X,Y);
trisurf(tri,X,Y,Z) % first plot
hold on
trisurf(tri,X2,Y2,Z2) % second plot
trisurf(tri,X,Y,Z2-Z2i) % difference
hold off
```

Hope it should work if your x and y data in both sets are in the same region.

**EDIT:** Use INTERP2 for X and Y generated by meshgrid. For vectors and how to use TriScatteredInterp see other SO question: [How Do I Generate a 3-D Surface From Isolines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672176/how-do-i-generate-a-3-d-surface-from-isolines)

Comment: Can't get interp2 to work.  I think because X Y and X2 Y2 are not the same length.